# How to check if the Angular test using the native elements has resulted the error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to check if the Angular test using the native elements has resulted the error?

My test is:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MikeComponent } from './mike.component';

describe('MikeComponent', () => {
   let component: MikeComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<MikeComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MikeComponent]
   })
     .compileComponents();
 }));

 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MikeComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

 it('press the button', () => {
   let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
   button.click();
 });
});
```

When I run the test it succeeds, but there is in the log message like this:

```
...
ERROR: 'ERROR', TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
...
```

How I can check in the test that error happened? I don't want use the Protractor for accessing the browser log. But some other library or solution would be interesting.

I know that I can add the expectations for the native elements, but now that is not my goal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with:

```
  let isErrors = false;

  console.error = function () {
    isErrors = true;
  }

  let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  button.click();

  expect(isErrors).toBe(false);
```